# php variable magic. How php work with decimal and hex

Tags: php

```
$a1 = 010;

print (int)$a1;
```

print value = 8

Anybody can explain how php made this result?
Because 010 in hex = 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`010` is `10` in base-8, i.e. `8` in base-10.

Full reference from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

```
<?php

    $a = 1234; // decimal number
    $a = -123; // a negative number
    $a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
    $a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
    $a = 0b11111111; // binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not hex. It's octal.

For HEX:
$a = 0x10;

For octal 
$a = 010;

For HEX number, you have to start with 0x.